# How to return Custom HTTP Status code + message in IEnumerable<xxx.Models.xxx> function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

```
public IEnumerable<xxx.Models.Product> ReviewAll(string para1, string para2, string para3, int para4)
{
    return //HTTPStatusCode
}
```

Currently I'm using this

```
int HTTPResponse=400;
return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)HTTPResponse, "InvalidID");
```

But this returns an error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How to fix this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactor action to return `HttpResponseMessage`

```
public HttpResponseMessage ReviewAll(string para1, string para2, string para3, int para4) {
    if(some_condition) {
        //...code removed for brevity

        //if request is invalid then return appropriate status response
        int HTTPResponse = 400;
        var response = Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)HTTPResponse);
        response.ReasonPhrase = "InvalidID";
        return response;
    } else {
        //If the data is valid I need to return the data segment,
        IEnumerable<xxx.Models.Product> responseBody = //...code removed for brevity
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, responseBody);//include data with an HttpStatus.Ok (200) response
    }
}
```

Comment: No Nkosi.I cannot refactor action to return HttpResponseMessage because I'm using "Product" model inside the function. Isn't there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: What you use in the function doesn't matter. the framework will get the model from the body of the response and return that to the caller, which is what i did in the else statement. this way you have the flexibility to return a proper status code with the response.

Comment: This function not only returns the HTTP Response but also the data.

Need to return data which is based on xxx.Models.Product type if condition is true and return HTTP response when condition is false. :-)

Comment: I gave you the solution based on the information provided but you indicated that it is incorrect.

Comment: I cannot make the return type of the function as HttpResponseMessage because the function needs to return data based on xxx.Models.Product. If the data is valid I need to return the data segment, otherwise I have to return the HTTPStatus message. If I make the return type of the function as HTTPResponseMessage how can I return the data when success. That's why I'm asking How to return HTTPResponse Message while the function's data type is xxx.Models.Product. Thanks:-)

Comment: You are overthinking this. the data will be returned in the body of the response. look at the answer closely. In fact I think you need to reread about actions and controllers so that you can understand what I explained to you before. There is nothing more I can do for you now.

Comment: Nice link because I never knew it was called a ["Reason phrase"](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)